# Where can I ask questions about TOEFL and GRE?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, stackexchange

I've a couple of questions about TOEFL and GRE tests. I'm a bit wary of whether questions on this topic is on-topic at this site or not?

My question is mostly about *materials* of those tests not technical issues (like where/when is it held or somethings like that)

If this sort of questions is on-topic so signal me to start them off or otherwise please tell me if there is any site suitable for this sort of questions on the Stack Exchange or not?

Comment: We have our own [approved resources](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english) page on meta, but I think these are more specialised materials that you should get from the relevant organisations. [This one for TOEFL](https://www.ets.org/toefl/ibt/prepare/) and [this one for GRE](http://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/prepare/?WT.ac=grehome_greprepare_b_150213). Questions about those materials are likely to be Off Topic on the main site.

Comment: The general consensus seems to be that this site is for discussion of the English language.  It's not meant to address all the challenges English language learners might face.  (I'd be fine with such questions, but as I understand it I'm the only one.)  I don't believe there is any SE site where questions of this sort are on topic.

Comment: What do you mean, your "question is mostly about the *materials?*  "Maybe you can ask your question before it's deemed to be on- or off-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like these are not on topic on ELL; they're more "customer support" questions for the organizations themselves. If you run across a question about the English language while studying for them, we'd be more than happy to answer it. But materials questions should be directed to the relevant organization.

Thanks for asking!